# PHP и MySQL. Запрос в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Имеется таблица со снятыми показаниями портативной метеостанции (одна строка, новые значения заменяют предыдущие, уже реализовано), откуда берётся текущее значение температуры `temp`, и ещё одна таблица с типами одежды и соответствующими диапазонами температур (вида "ID, мин. температура, макс. температура, одежда", диапазоны не пересекаются). 
Сложилась следующая задача: на основе значения температуры воздуха из первой таблицы вывести соответствующее значение одежды. 
Пробовал гуглить, но так ничего и не понял. По факту, насколько я понимаю, нужно взять ID из второй таблицы, через цикл постепенно увеличивать его, по ходу выполняя сравнение вида `mintemp <= temp <= maxtemp`. И если условие выполняется, то вывести соответствующее значение одежды на экран. Но связать всё это дело с MySQL вызывает у меня затруднение.

Comment: Лучше почитайте что нибудь по sql, потому что любую информацию из БД можно получить одним запросом. буквально что то вроде `select одежда from показания join одежда on показания.temp between одежда.mintemp and одежда.maxtemp where каие-то-условия-для-выборки-нужного-показания`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM odejda, pokazaniya 
WHERE odejda.mintemp <= pokazaniya.temp 
OR odejda.maxtemp >= pokazaniya.temp 
//если температура одежды меньше или равно показанию, или если температура
//одежды больше или равно показанию
```